# How to forward form submission after custom handling

Tags: php, wordpress, http

I need to send a form submission to a specific endpoint but before I do that I want to do some custom handling on it. So I set up a custom handling function but now I can't figure out how to get the POST and forward it to the final endpoint.

Here is what I have:

```
<form class="" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php') ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="bb_submit_email">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="example@email.com" required>
        <?php echo wp_nonce_field('submit-email', '_mynonce'); ?>
        <input type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-primary form-button" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

- 

```
add_action('admin_post_bb_submit_email', 'bb_handle_email_submit');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_bb_submit_email', 'bb_handle_email_submit');

function bb_handle_email_submit() {

    $logger = wc_get_logger();
         

    if ( !isset($_POST['_mynonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_mynonce'], 'submit-email')) {
      $logger->add('submit-email-debug', 'nonce failed!'); 

      return;
    }
```

When my custom handler is triggered, is there a way to get the post request and forward it to an external endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) at the end of `bb_handle_email_submit` function?

```
function bb_handle_email_submit() {
   // Your script above 
   wp_redirect(home_url('/thanks'));
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to redirect the user. I'm trying to redirect the POST request

Answer (score 0):

You can make a HTTP POST request to your endpoint from your custom form handler. The article [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) describes how to make HTTP POST request.

The $_POST variable contains the contents of the form submission. You need to include this variable in your HTTP POST request to the remote endpoint.